# Psuedo-tty allocation in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tty

In docker, I can simply use the `-t` switch to have `docker run` allocate a pseudo-tty (in these examples I'm using `nohup` to detach from my real tty):

```
$ nohup docker run    debian tty   # Produces "not a tty"
$ nohub docker run -t debian tty   # Produces "/dev/pts/0"
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result with docker-compose. I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myservice:
    image: debian
    tty: true
```

The I run it with and without `nohup`:

```
$       docker-compose run myservice tty   # Produces "/dev/pts/0"
$ nohup docker-compose run myservice tty   # Produces "not a tty"
```

The [documentation of `docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) says that I can use `-T` to *disable*  the allocation of a pseudo-tty, but there does not seem to be a way to explicitely *enable* it (which should not be necessary as by default a tty should be allocated).

> `-T` Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose run` allocates a TTY.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems like you want to run in the background ` docker-compose run -d myservice`, you can use `-d`, as nohup send service to background

Comment: `nohup` in my question simply emulates the situation I find myself in when my script is executed. The script does not have a tty. The actual image contains some code that needs a tty.

Answer (score 22):

Include the following in your `docker-compose.yml` for your service:

```
services:
  myservice:
    ...
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
```